# Submenus of the Menu control are hide behind the webpage images in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I am designing a website. I have created a simple menu(without sitemap) in master page and a web page called home.
The problem is that when I hosted this website submenu's of the menu control are hide behind the images of home webpage and if the any webpage has no image all Submenus are appears.

Have any problem in my menu creation. I have copy my code in this window but due to some reason it not shown.

Please help to shortout my problem
Here is my code:

```
                                            <dynamichoverstyle BackColor="LightBlue" Font-Bold="true" />

                                            </asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to help without the source code but did you try playing with the z-index :
http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp